# Using SoCo to create Sonos groups

Tags: python, sonos

Does anyone know if it's possible to programmatically create a group with SoCo?

For instance, let's say I'd like to group 5 devices together and specify the coordinator:

```
ZoneGroup(uid='...', coordinator=SoCo("192.168.0.115"), members=set([SoCo("192.168.0.101"), SoCo("192.168.0.111"), SoCo("192.168.0.102"), SoCo("192.168.0.100"), SoCo("192.168.0.115")]))
```

I can instantiate this object locally, but don't know how to then send the configuration over to the devices to set the topology.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  First unjoin the zone you want to be the group leader.  This removes it from any previous group.  Then join each of the other zones to that zone.  You know your network, so you can come up with better names.

```
one, two, three, four, five = [SoCo("192.168.0.101"), SoCo("192.168.0.111"), SoCo("192.168.0.102"), SoCo("192.168.0.100"), SoCo("192.168.0.115")]

one.unjoin()
two.join(one)
three.join(one)
four.join(one)
five.join(one)
```

You can check group membership with one.group (an attribute, not a method).

```
one.group
```

Everything is accessed from the SoCo objects.  No need to deal with the ZoneGroup class directly.

Comment: By the way, if this is ALL of your sonos devices, there's a shortcut: one.partymode().

Answer (score 1):

You can call `partymode()` to group all available speakers into a group:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import soco
# Use a specific speaker named Livingroom to be the master
device = soco.discovery.by_name("Livingroom")
device.group.coordinator.partymode()
```

In case you don't care about which speaker should be the master you can find any one of them:

```
# Use any speaker as the master
device = soco.discovery.any_soco()
```

See [soco.core](http://docs.python-soco.com/en/latest/api/soco.core.html) for more details.